# como borrar correctamente una fila en python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

utilizo este codigo para borrar filas, pero si agrego nuevamente una fila nueva el auto increment de SQLite sigue x el ultimo numero donde se quedo, ejemplo borre #2, si creo una fila nueva salta al #3 cuando debio ser #2,

> existe alguna manera de tambien borrar el numero que se le asigna del auto-incremento?

```
def Eliminar_articulo_orden_compra(self):
        selected = self.cuadro_blanco_compra.selection()[0]
        id = self.cuadro_blanco_compra.item(selected)["values"][0]#me devuelve el numero del articulo 
        query = f'DELETE FROM orden_compra WHERE referencia = {id}'#que conincide con la columna referencia
        self.run_query(query)
```

Estaba mirando alternativas y vi que podia utilizar eventos, pero estos eventos utilizan los ejes Y y X del mouse, este si me da el numero correcto de ID no importa cuanto borre,

> existe alguna manera de que no sea por evento y sea por boton?

```
col = self.cuadro_blanco_articulos.identify_row(event.y)
```

Comment: El valor en si no tiene importancia; puede ser cualquier número mayor que el anterior.

Comment: @CandidMoe te equibocas, si el id de la columna es 10 y el id proporcionado por python es 3, fallara. por eso pregunto si existe una manera de borrar correctamente por id.

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. Es decir, buscas que tanto en sqlite como en el treeview, los ids sean consecutivos? tipo 1,2,3... en lugar de 1,2,4... cuando borras un registro?

Comment: @DanteS. agrego algo, actualiza la tabla a +1, agrego de nuevo  +2, luego +3 etc.... pero si borro algo la numeracion no se recetea, ejemplo: borre el 3 cuando agrege algo, lo agregara como #4 en vez de #3,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al menos en sqlite3, una columna autoincrement hace solo lo que dice su nombre, incrementar el valor automaticamente. Pero NO disminuye automaticamente.

Esto nos obliga a hacerlo manualmente.

#### Eliminando una sola fila

Si vas a borrar las filas de a una, podemos luego de borrar la fila hacer un update que le reste 1 a todos los id mayores al id borrado. Si el id es numerico e incrementa de a uno, entonces esto significa "desde el id borrado".

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE tabla(id INT)")

for i in range(0, 10):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabla(id) VALUES (?)", (i,))


def print_table():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tabla")

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row)

id = 4

cursor.execute("DELETE FROM tabla WHERE id=?", (id,))

print("Luego de eliminar...")
print_table()
print()

# Actualizamos el contador que dice que id sigue.
cursor.execute("UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = seq - 1 WHERE name = 'tabla'")
cursor.execute("UPDATE tabla SET id=id - 1 WHERE id > ?", (id,))

print("Luego de acomodar...")
print_table()
```

Produce

```
Luego de eliminar...
(0,)
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(5,)
(6,)
(7,)
(8,)
(9,)

Luego de acomodar...
(0,)
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(4,)
(5,)
(6,)
(7,)
(8,)
```

#### Eliminando varias filas

Ahora, si tu delete afecta a más de una fila, ten en cuenta que esta idea no servirá. Tal vez convendría más crear tu propia función en sqlite o en Python, o usar una tabla auxiliar. Una sola consulta no da abasto a esa complejidad.

Lo más probable es que la primera opción sea lo más conveniente, pero no tengo conocimiento de como lo podría hacer.

Te paso una función que hace esto mismo, pero que tiene desventajas. (Nota, al usar formateo de cadenas, esta función es vulnerable a la [inyección sql](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL))

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE tabla(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nombre TEXT)")

for i in range(0, 10):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabla(nombre) VALUES (?)", (str(i),))


def restart_ids(table, idcol):
    start = 0

    # reinicio a start el contador automatico
    cursor.execute("UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = ? WHERE name = 'tabla'", (start,))

    # cargo todos los nombres de columnas en la tabla y luego filtro
    # para desempaquetar la tupla y eliminar la columna que hace de id
    cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO(?)", (table,))
    columns = [col for (col,) in cursor.fetchall() if(col != idcol)]
    
    # cargo en memoria todos los datos de la tabla en memoria
    cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM %s" % (",".join(columns), table))
    resultado = cursor.fetchall()

    # elimino el contenido de la tabla
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM %s" % table)

    # recorro cada fila y la vuelvo a insertar sin pasar la id
    # lo cual motiva la aparición del valor default que será la id contando desde 0.
    for row in resultado:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabla(%s) VALUES (%s)" % (",".join(columns), ",".join("?" for _ in range(len(columns)))), row)

def print_table():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY id")

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row)

cursor.execute("DELETE FROM tabla WHERE id=4")

print("Antes del reinicio...")
print_table()

restart_ids("tabla", idcol="id")

print("Después del reinicio...")
print_table()
```

- Esta función carga casi toda la tabla en la memoria del cliente. Esto significa un problema de seguridad y un exceso de uso de memoria (de hecho, la memoria del cliente podría no alcanzar para tablas muy grandes)
- Al pasar a través de Python, se hacen procedimientos de conversión que en realidad resultarían innecesarios, pues no se modifica ni usan los valores en ningún momento. Además, Python es considerablemente más lento que sqlite, ya que sqlite está implementado en c, que es más rapido.

#### Conclusión

Eliminar aquellos "huecos" en una columna autoincrement es costoso en terminos de rendimiento e, incluso, complejidad. Ya que, por lo menos, requiere en muchos casos recorrer buena parte de la tabla acomodando los ids.

Mi recomendación, es que busques otra forma de mostrar ids consecutivos (Python ofrece la función [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)) y otro primary key.

Por ejemplo, veo que tenés una columna llamada orden_compra. Si el valor de esa columna nunca se repite, podrías usar dicha columna como primary key y, cuando quieras eliminar el registro, utilizas la orden de compra como si fuera una id.

Comment: gracias x las molestias, al final me descarte por la 2da opcion ya que como cuentas no funcionaria si elimino varias filas,  Utilize el metodo: identify_row que funciona por eventos, tuve q eliminar los botones de la ventana, pero funciono siempre elige el ID correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo el codigo por si alguien se le presenta la misma emergencia, donde self.item es el ID que utilizara el query para eliminar. siempre tomara la fila correcta no importa cuantas filas borres.
Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 def createWindow(self):
        self.popup = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
        self.popup.add_command(label="precio #1", command=lambda: self.copiar_fila_precio())
        self.popup.add_command(label="precio #2", command=lambda: self.copiar_fila_precio2())
        self.popup.add_command(label="precio #3", command=lambda: self.copiar_fila_precio3())
        self.popup.add_separator()
        self.popup.add_command(label="Borrar Articulo", command=lambda: self.borrado_articulos_almacen()) # , command=next) etc...
        self.popup.add_command(label="Informacion", command=lambda: self.closeWindow())

        #Button(root, text="Exit", command=lambda: self.closeWindow()).pack()

    def borrado_articulos_almacen(self):
        try:
            query = f'DELETE FROM productos WHERE nro = {self.item}'#que conincide con la columna referencia
            self.run_query(query)
            self.consulta_productos()
        except:
            messagebox.showwarning("INFORMACION","No selecciono un Articulo de la lista")

    def closeWindow(self):
        messagebox.showwarning("INFORMACION","Basado en Python 3.0 Codeado por Wally Romero, Correo: yaretromero@hotmail.com")
        

        #self.edit_ventana_articulos_administrador.destroy()
        #sys.exit()

    def do_popup(self, event):#el evento que registra la coordenada Y de l fila, marcando el id agregado en ese momento
        self.item = self.cuadro_blanco_articulos.identify_row(event.y)
     
        #print('clicked item:', self.item)
        try:
            self.popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)

        finally:
            self.popup.grab_release()#termina el codigo poppop aqui
```